# 3D Data: Scale in BLL or in UI?

Tags: c#, user-interface, 3d, xna, scale

I'm developing a 3D world simulator (www.athpro.com) and internally it processes all game tiles (hexes) as 1.0 unit x 1.0 unit in dimensions. The UI is entirely separate, and is responsible for "scaling up" the data. The world data is analogous to a vector image. Now, I have a Helper which takes the World data and hands it off to the UI for rendering. I'm wondering... would it be simpler... and more sensible to also have the Helper be ignorant of scale and leave the scaling solely on the shoulder's of the UI?

In XNA, you could just render everything in the native (1x1) scale (which would probably be much smaller than you'd want it for your game world) and use a matrix transformation to scale it up by whatever factor you want in one pass, right? That's one of the reasons I'm thinking of leaving it to the UI.

It also keeps the Helper a lot cleaner to not have it scaling every vector etc. All the objects are passed via interfaces w/ get-only properties, so in my Helper DLL I'm having to create implementations of each in order to just scale up it's values. Seems like a lot of clutter and overhead for something which might be simpler in the UI.

I know it's kind of an odd question, but I'd love any advice you have. I'd especially appreciate the input of game developers especially.

Thanks!

Comment: if you don't get anything satisfactory here, try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view is that you should keep object representation and rendering separate, so i guess that would mean having scaling in your UI object(s) with the rendering, since you're only scaling so you can render.

You shouldn't need to manipulate each object's coordinates/scale, when you draw just use a single matrix transform when drawing your objects.